# how to give dynamic variable for href attribute inline colorbox

Tags: jquery, dynamic, inline, href, colorbox

How to change inline colorbox 'href' dynamic 
like i want when i click on a 'tr' colorbox take it 'title' to 'href' 
and show it 
like

```
<table>
    <tr title="project1">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="project2">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="project1" style="display:none">this is about project one</div>
<div id="project2" style="display:none">this is about project two </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
   $("#" +  $(this).attr("title")).show();
});
```

On row click, this takes the title attribute, uses it as an `ID` selector and shows the matching element.  If you want to hide the others when this happens, give your divs a class like `class="project"` and just add a call to hide the test before showing, like this:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
   $(".project").hide();
   $("#" +  $(this).attr("title")).show();
});
```

Comment: thank alot dude for early responce, i got the idea and tried this it workde for me .. thanx again
<code>
$("tr").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: function() {
       var url = $(this).attr('title');
      return '#' + url ;
    } }); 

</code>